# Would i benefit by running an OS on my HDD but installing my games on a SSD?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, gaming

I currently have Windows on my HDD.

I just bought a SSD and i'm pondering about installing Ubuntu on it.
Thing is most of my favorite games are windows only.

Let's say i'm running Windows (installed on the HDD) but my game files are located in the SSD:

1 - Would i still benefit from the SSD's speed?

2 - Does it make a difference having Win on the SSD and running both OS+games on SSD in comparison of OS (HDD) + Games (SSD)? (*not* considering OS boot time. I'm only concerned about game performance)

Answer (score 1):

You won't see any game performance improvements other than faster loading times. It won't make your games run any smoother. You may load into the game faster than your friends, though.

A forewarning about the Ubuntu/Windows thing - I wouldn't recommend dual-booting unless you know what you're doing or are up for a good challenge. If you are going to end up putting games and Ubuntu on your SSD, you'll need to make sure they're on separate partitions on the SSD because if you put the games on the Linux partition Windows won't be able to access them.

Comment: Yes i was talking about the loading times performance. I don't intend on having two OS on the same drive. Only two drives each one with a single OS.

Answer (score 1):

If you keep Windows (OS) and the games together on the SSD, you will see much faster startup times. I see that on my own machine here. Parking the games only on an SSD will not speed things up as noted in the other post in this thread.

I use both Kali and Ubuntu in Virtual machines to satisfy that need

Comment: VMs are a good alternative to dual-booting, you can still get the full functionality of Linux but you'll still be able to run Windows and keep compatibility with Microsoft Office and your games. Although Linux has made major advancements in that department in the last few years... It should also be noted that WSL works great for development of Linux-compatible programs in Windows.

Comment: I know the OS won't boot faster. But the thing is, will the **games** boot faster?

Comment: Only a bit faster - not really noticeable.

Comment: I'll second @John on that one - I have used an SSD in the past for games and I honestly can't really tell a difference between when I run them off the hard drive vs the SSD.